# reading multiple files of multiple folders in zip, using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I read multiple .txt files in multiple folders within a .zip file with Pandas specifically? I have been looking around a lot, I see that you can read a zip file with Pandas or just read files within a folder, but they are not exactly what I am looking for. Let's say I have this structure

```
.zip1

1. Folder1
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
3. Folder2
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
```

I wanna be able to open zip, iterate through folders, iterate through .txt files, count the occurences of each word and assign them a label/symbol. I am new to Python and ML so any help would be appreciated

Comment: use `os.listdir()` to get a list of files in the directory. Then iterate through the list elements, if an element (filename or foldername) has no extension then move to that directory and list files again. If it has an extension and that is `.txt` then open as file and do your thing.

Comment: Hi Mooshak. It helps a lot if you show what you've already tried. People here are happy to help, but only if you show that you've made an attempt yourself first

Answer (score 0):

From the zipfile `data.zip`:

```
.
├── Folder1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
└── Folder2
    ├── file1.txt
    └── file2.txt
```

You can do:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('data.zip') as zf:
    for filename in zf.namelist():
        zinfo = zf.getinfo(filename)
        if not zinfo.is_dir():
            with zf.open(filename, 'r') as fp:
                print(f"{filename}:\n{fp.read()}\n")
                # do stuff here
```

Output:

```
Folder1/file2.txt:
b'consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore\n'

Folder1/file1.txt:
b'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n'

Folder2/file2.txt:
b'ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat\n'

Folder2/file1.txt:
b'et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation\n'
```

As I don't know the structure of your files, I can't help you more.